# What is a nice way to obtain a slice partially indexed by another tensor in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose we have a tensor `x` with unknown first dimension (for example `[?, 32, 32, 3]`), and another tensor `i` that is actually a scalar. Is there a nice way to obtain the `i`-th slice of `x` split by first dimension, for example, to get a tensor of dimension `[32, 32, 3]`? I'm new to TensorFlow and was only able to come up with this extremely clumsy solution.

```
index = tf.concat(0, [i, tf.constant([0, 0, 0], tf.int64)])
size = [1, x.get_shape()[1].value, x.get_shape()[2].value, x.get_shape()[3].value]
result = tf.unpack(tf.slice(x, index, size))[0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that `-1` is a special argument to the [`tf.slice()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#slice) `size` argument, meaning "all remaining elements in that dimension". Then, assuming `i` is a scalar (and not a length-1 vector as it seems to be in your code snippet), you can do:

```
result = tf.squeeze(tf.slice(x, tf.pack([index, 0, 0, 0]), [1, -1, -1, -1]), [0])
```

Alternatively, you can use [`tf.gather()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#gather) to select one or more slices from a tensor on the zeroth dimension. In this case, `i` must be a vector:

```
i = tf.expand_dims(i, 0)  # Converts `i` to a vector if it is a scalar.
result = tf.squeeze(tf.gather(x, i), [0])
```

In both cases, the [`tf.squeeze()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#squeeze) op removes the 0th dimension to give a three-dimensional result.