# Slicing an image Tensor with bounding box Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have input image Tensor with shape `[?, 448, 448, 3]` and my network predicts a bounding box with shape `[?, 4]`. I want to slice my image tensor with the bounding box tensor and re-size the resulting tensor into a fixed size image for further processing.

Is this possible with tensorflow (or even better, natively in Keras)? I have read the relevant questions. E.g, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597520/slicing-a-tensor-by-an-index-tensor-in-tensorflow), and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133088/what-is-a-nice-way-to-obtain-a-slice-partially-indexed-by-another-tensor-in-tens?rq=1), but they do not apply to when both the indexing tensor and the original tensor have an unknown first dimension.

Any help in the right direction is much appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way for you should be to use `tf.image.crop_and_resize`. From the documentation:

> Extracts crops from the input image tensor and bilinearly resizes them
>   (possibly  aspect ratio change) to a common output size specified by
>   crop_size. This is more general than the crop_to_bounding_box op which
>   extracts a fixed size slice from the input image and does not allow
>   resizing or aspect ratio change.
>
> Returns a tensor with crops from the input image at positions defined
>   at the bounding box locations in boxes. The cropped boxes are all
>   resized (with bilinear interpolation) to a fixed size = [crop_height,
>   crop_width]. The result is a 4-D tensor [num_boxes, crop_height,
>   crop_width, depth].